# How to use Kendo UI PullParameters function along with Pull To Refresh?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I'm trying to have my ListView working with Pull To Refresh. Nevertheless, I can't have the listview refresehd.

basically, when a user trigger pull to refresh, it should replace the whole content of the list view.

Here is how I have handled my list view and the pull to refresh:

```
function handle_geolocation_query( position )
{
    $.when( Event.getEventsNearby( position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, radius, limit, offset, key ) ).done( function( response )
    {
        var dataToBeCached = new Array();

        //In order not to cache the same results twice
        var previousContent;

        if( response.containsResults )
        {
            var results = response.results;

            //Remove previous markers
            Map.clearMarkers();

            // Add Markers on the map
            Map.setMarkerPosition( position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, "grey" );
            for ( var i=0; i<results.length; i++ )
            {
                Map.setMarkerPosition( results[i].lat, results[i].lng, "green");
                results[i]["index"] = i;
            }

            setItem("events", JSON.stringify( results ), 1);

            var template = Handlebars.compile( $( '#eventListTemplate' ).html() );
            $("#list-container").kendoMobileListView({
                template : template,
                dataSource: kendo.data.DataSource.create(results),
                fixedHeaders: false,
                pullToRefresh: true,
                pullParameters: function(item) {
                    console.log("pull");
                    //Here, another AJAX call to get the new results
                    $.when( Event.getEventsNearby( position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, radius, limit, offset, key ) ).done( function( response )
                    {
                        console.log("when");
                        //I can see I'm getting my results properly here.
                        console.log(response.results);
                        //Doesn't work ...
                        return response.results;
                    });
                }
            });

            $( document ).trigger( "wallReady" );

            //Retrieve the different user conversations:
            updateListOfChats();
        }
    } );
};
```

What should I put into the pullParameters function to make it work ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pull parameters function should **return** the parameters about to be passed in the next request, which is performed by the datasource component itself. Please refer to the [API reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/mobile/listview#configuration-pullParameters) for more details and a working example.

Comment: Thanks Petyo, I've been trying to play with it but I think I am missing something. I do have a return function in my pullparameters (it's in the when, not sure if that's fine though). In my test, what I return in `return response.results;` is exactly the same as what I pass to `dataSource: kendo.data.DataSource.create(results),`. But it still doesn't work. could you enlight me on this please?